# How do I create a pop up window containing a canvas?

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, system.drawing

I'm creating a little paint program and I want to have a canvas pop up when I click on a button.

```
private void buttonNewDrawing_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(mainCanvas);
}
```

Doesn't work obviously because it's asking for a string. but what can I then use instead of a `MessageBox` to just have the canvas `mainCanvas` pop up so I can use it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to show a `MessageBox`? Is the `mainCanvas` a canvas control?

Comment: No the message box is just an example of what type of popup I want to do, i just want it to open a new window and show my canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 window = new Window1();
    window.Show();
}
```

Window1.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: How do I create the new xaml in the same project?
I already have a the canvas outside of my GUI, can I somehow just hide it and show it when the button is clicked?
The event args looks good, thank you!